# Update a column based on the value of other column

Tags: excel-formula

[My excel sheet looks like below.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jh1an.png)

I would like place value of 2 in column C if complexity level is Difficult. If low then 0.5 and if medium then 0.75.

Please let me know if there is any formula available or I have to write a marco for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IN C2:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX({2,0.75,0.5},MATCH(B2,{"Difficult","Medium","Low"},0)),"Not a Choice")
```

Comment: any advantage over nested IF?

Comment: Shorter and easier to maintain if the values or results change. @ForwardEd

Comment: @ArijitBiswas please choose one to mark as correct by clicking that check mark by the answer you choose.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach

In an empty column or on another sheet build a table of words and corresponding values. Lest say you build your table on Sheet2 with B2 in the upper left corner and you used a header row.

[image: Example Setup]

You could use the following formula on the in the C column

```
=VLOOKUP(B2,Sheet2!$B$3:INDEX(Sheet2!$C:$C,AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW(Sheet2!B:B)*(Sheet2!B:B<>""),1)),2,0)
```

Proof of Concept

[image: POC]

Caveats:  You cannot have any data in sheet2 column B below your last entry you want to check for.

Advantages:  This formula automatically increases the size of the lookup table as rows of information are added.  If you needed to add more degrees of difficulty in the future you could do so with out needing to change your formula.  you would just add the new word to the bottom of the list.

To cover the case where a difficulty value is not found in the list, you can wrap the formula above in an IFERROR formula

```
=IFERROR(formula above,"Difficulty not found, add to table?")
```

EDIT:

In light of Scott Craner's suggestion the lookup formula can be simplified to:

```
=VLOOKUP(B2,Sheet2!$B:$C,2,0)
```

Comment: Just the simple `VLOOKUP(B2, Sheet2!B:C,2,FALSE)` would suffice.

Comment: Fair enough,  I thought it may be important to limit the range but if you have to look at the full column to limit the range your really aren't saving anything are you? @ScottCraner

Comment: VLookup, is not an Array type formula, so there is no advantage or disadvantage to using full column over set references.